# Generation of tuples in apriori algorithm

Tags: python, apriori

I am writing the apriori algorithm in python and have to create a combination of tuples. For example given:

```
(1, 3), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 5), (3, 5)
```

the algorithm will return:

```
(1,2,3), (1,2,5), (1,3,5), (2,3,5)
```

I have tried combinations() in itertools but that doesn't seem to work for tuples.

```
list(combinations(keys, k+2))
```

Is there a general join algorithm in python that joins two tuples based on the k value? For instance, given a tuple, the algorithm will join the tuples and return a new set of tuples?

Comment: `import itertools; xss = (1, 3), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 5), (3, 5); items = sorted({x for xs in xss for x in xs}); print(list(itertools.combinations(items, 3)))`

Comment: Where does the `k` from?

Comment: k is just the iteration we are on in the apriori algorithm